# Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception'

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx

Today I updated my ubuntu box and it reset my php settings. Now I am getting this error.

```
   <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'The memcached extension must be loaded for using this backend !' in /home/sam/Documents/repos/epic/vendor/Zend/Cache.php:209
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/sam/Documents/repos/epic/vendor/Zend/Cache/Backend/Libmemcached.php(100): Zend_Cache::throwException('The memcached e...')
    #1 /home/sam/Documents/repos/epic/application/bootstrap.php(30): Zend_Cache_Backend_Libmemcached-&gt;__construct(Array)
    #2 /home/sam/Documents/repos/epic/vendor/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(669): Bootstrap-&gt;_initDatabase()
    #3 /home/sam/Documents/repos/epic/vendor/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(622): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract-&gt;_executeResource('database')
    #4 /home/sam/Documents/repos/epic/vendor/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(586): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract-&gt;_bootstrap(NULL)
    #5 /home/sam/Documents/repos/epic/vendor/Zend/Application.php(355): Zend in <b>/home/sam/Documents/repos/epic/vendor/Zend/Cache.php</b> on line <b>209</b><br />
```

I tried reverting back to the earlier php version (php 5.4) but this problem is still there. Where exactly this has gone wrong ?

Comment: You need to install Memcached php extension... yum install php-memcached (or apt-get install php-memcached)

Comment: Tried. No difference.

Comment: Restart apache after it's been installed, should be alright after that